# Jquery AJAX request no longer completes when Python tries to use posted data

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, post, cgi

I am using JQuery to make an AJAX request to a Python script. After being totally unable to get the request to successfully complete and send a response, I started over, to see if I could figure out exactly what was causing the problem. My AJAX call looks like this:

```
$.ajax({url:'http://localhost/cgi-bin/ajaxtest.py',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {sources:addressList,number:numAddr},
}).done(function(data){
      alert (data);
}).fail(function(){alert("error");}).always(function(data,textStatus,jqXHR){alert(jqXHR.status)});
```

So essentially I'm calling the `ajaxtest.py` script, and posting to it `addressList`, which is a string with `\t` as a delimiter, and `numAddr`, which is the number of addresses in `addressList`

Now I started pretty basic with my Python script. In fact, I didn't do anything at all with the values I was passing. The basic script I started with looked like this:

```
#!/Users/myname/Python/Python
import telnetlib
import sys
import cgi
import cgitb
from multiprocessing import Pool

cgitb.enable()
print "Content-type: text/html\n"

result_list = []

def counter(x):
    return x*x

def log_result(result):
    result_list.append(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool=Pool(processes=4)

    for x in range(0, 4):
        pool.apply_async(counter,args = (x,),callback = log_result)
        result_list.append("ho")
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print(result_list)
```

This script wasn't really designed to do anything practical, but more to test what works and what doesn't, in this case to see if the pool functions were causing my previous problems. It turns out they were not;the script ran perfectly when called by my javascript, the correct response was given, and the AJAX status code made it to 200.

The problem comes when I attempt to do something with the string or integer I post via AJAX. Whenever I add the line `data=cgi.FieldStorage()` to the script, it seems to get stuck. If it matters, I added it right underneath `cgitb.enable()`. When the AJAX call is made, nothing happens, and then when I go to close or refresh the page, the `.fail` method kicks in. I'm not sure why this is happening, as the only change being made is adding the variable to hold what has been posted.

Is there something that I'm missing? I've used AJAX successfully before, although I believe this is the first time I'm doing it via JQuery.

Comment: Try it with get method and tell me does it work?

Comment: @zoran404 It did work with `type:'GET'`, but I'm worried about when the string of data being sent is long, isn't there a character limit?

Comment: 2000 characters is the limit that you should have in plan. is that enough for you?

Comment: Generally it should not exceed 2000 characters, but the data length is variable, and in certain cases I can see it going above that, which obviously will not work.

Do you know why it is that my POST had not worked? Was it a formatting error, or am I missing something about POST implementation?

Comment: Actually I don't know python, all I can tell you is to google how to do this and see what is the difference between your and their code.

Comment: I'm actually having this problem as well.
It used to work, but now all AJAX POST requests are not received by `cgi.FieldStorage()`. Strange part is it used to work and now it's suddenly broken.